# RecyclerView adapter notifyDataSetChanges() not refreshing recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have set up a RecyclerView like this

```
@Override
public void setTenData(List<Data> dataList) {
    Timber.d("set ten drugs size %s",dataList.size());
        this.dataList = dataList;
        dataListAdapter = new DataListingAdapter(getActivity(), this.dataList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);

}
```

And in another method I get new data and when I try to refresh the RecyclerView like this

```
@Override
public void setNewsData(List<Data> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    Timber.d("size of news data %s",this.dataList.size());
    dataListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The RecyclerView doesn't get updated. What might be the problem?

Comment: set it to the adapter

Comment: it works that way, but shouldn't it be also working correctly the way I've done.

Comment: @theanilpaudel no, your way changes the reference in your view from the old list to the new list. Your adapter's reference still points to the old list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your new data in your adapter, not just in your view

Comment: You answer is totally correct, and with you permission I will add to be sure that  notifiDataSetChanged was done on MainThread :)

Comment: this.dataList is set in the adapter.

Comment: Add a function in your adapter: `public void setDataList(List<Data> dataList)` and in it set the new data to the adapter's list. And as @Neonamu said, make sure that notifyDataSetChanged is called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void setTenData(List<Data> dataList) {
    Timber.d("set ten drugs size %s",dataList.size());
        this.dataList = dataList;
        dataListAdapter = new DataListingAdapter(getActivity(), this.dataList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);
dataListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clear your list and add new data to it and than notify adapter. Here i modified your code:

```
@Override
public void setNewsData(List<Data> dataList) {
    this.dataList.clear();
    this.dataList.addAll(dataList);
    dataListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Data class there extends RealmObject so we can't clear and then addAll in this list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void setNewsData(List<Data> dataList) {
    this.dataList.addAll(dataList); //        if datalist has only new data
    //this.dataList = dataList;//        if datalist has all data
    Timber.d("size of news data %s",this.dataList.size());
}
```

And then call the main thread;

```
dataListAdapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
dataListAdapter.setNewsData(dataList);
dataListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```